# Getting value found in in_array

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is it possible to get the value found `in_array`
I have an encrypted database, I want to find an email address for verification using codeignitor. My models looks something like this

```
public function check_user($login){

    $users = $this->db->select('email', 'username')->from('user')->get()->result_array();

    if(in_array($login,$this->encryption->decrypt($users))){



    }
    else{

        return FALSE;

    }

}
```

Inside the `if()` I will have found whether there is any matching results, but I want the value itself so I can use it to query the table like

```
$this->db->from('user')->where('email',$email)->get()->row();
```

That will enable me get the password to verify it.

Any other suggestion is welcome

Comment: Is this for passwords? Then you should use `password_verify()` instead. Why do you encrypt the username or email?

Comment: I need to get the row which matches that specific user so I can get the hashed password

Comment: Like I said, why do you encrypt the username or email? It makes harder to work with.

Comment: Its harder but more secure

Comment: That's not where you should focus your efforts. It's not really more secure if you just protect your system, by using prepared statements, SSL, etc. It just makes everything much harder for yourself without helping much, and obscuring the username doesn't really make a difference. I recommend you just store that in plaintext; any sensitive data can be encrypted. But the username isn't sensitive data.

Comment: Imagine if you want to join a table to your user-table - you can't do it with an encrypted username. Or search the database for a specific user; then you have to select ALL of the rows, which isn't effective at all. The username can be stored in plaintext, as it doesn't improve security by obscuring it.

Comment: There is a reason why everything is encrypted. It is a requirement. And there is no search option in the entire system. Actually, everything else is working fine. I'm just one step away